# Mnetgen: bash-files and syntax errors - where's the bug?

Tags: bash, makefile

I want to create *Multicommodity Min Cost Flow* instances with the help of 
[Mnetgen](http://www.di.unipi.it/optimize/Data/MMCF.html#MNetGen) but I have problems with the file called "batch" whose first lines are given by

```
# Batch file for generating MMCF problems with the mnetgen random generator
#
# For each n in {64, 128, 256} generates 12 instances for each pair (n, k)
# with k in {4, 8, 16 , ... , n}, using as input the parameters found
# in pr{n}.{k}/{n}-{k}-{h}.inp for h in {1, ... , 12}. The instances
# are left in the directory pr{n}.{k}
#
# At the end of the file, commented out, there are the instructions for
# generating the groups with n = 512 and n = 768: in the latter case,
# however, only 6 instances for each group are generated.
#
# In a Unix environment, simply type "source batch" or "csh < batch"

foreach i ( 64 )
foreach j ( 4 8 16 32 64 )
foreach h ( 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 )

mnetgen pr$i.$j/$i-$j-$h.inp pr$i.$j/$i-$j-$h

end
end
end
...
```

What did I so far? First I added `#include <cstring>` to `mnetgen.c` to avoid errors. Then I typed `make` to get an executable file `mnetgen`. The last step would be to generate the instances by using the batch-file.

Using the hint in last comment line I get either

`bash: batch: Zeile 14: Syntaxfehler beim unerwarteten Wort »(«`
`bash: batch: Zeile 14: 'foreach i ( 64 )'`

or

`mnetgen: Command not found.`

How can I fix that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are trying to run a csh shell in bash.

To fix that, either run

```
csh myshell
```

or add on the first line:

```
#!/bin/csh
```

When running your command, Unix/linux will check the first line which will be seen as a kind of magic number and will prefix it by `/bin/csh`.

(there are better ways to do that maybe with `#!/bin/env csh`)

and for your `mnetgen` command which is not found, I suggest that you add the full path of your command in your script or add it to the system PATH.

Comment: Thank you! By adding `#!/bin/csh` to the first line and `mnetgen` to the paths and using `csh < batch` I got the right result.